# Linear forms and the dimension of the intersection of their kernel

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $E$  a finite dimensional vector space over a field $\mathbb F$ and $\dim E=n$ and let $(\ell_1,\ldots,\ell_k)$ a linearly independant family in $E^*$. The question is to prove that
$$\dim\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^k\ker \ell_i\right)=\dim E-k.$$

What I have tried so far: We complete $(\ell_1,\ldots,\ell_k)$ to a basis $(\ell_1,\ldots,\ell_n)$ of $E^*$ and we consider the map
$$f:E\rightarrow \mathbb F^n,\quad x\mapsto(\ell_1(x),\ldots,\ell_n(x))$$
then $\ker f=\{0\}$ since $0$ is the only vector that annihilates all the $\ell_i$ so we conclude that $f$ is an isomorphism but I don't know how I complete the proof or if there's another idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compose your map $f$ with the map $\pi: \mathbb{F}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{F}^k$ which projects onto the first $k$ coordinates.  Then $\pi \circ f: E \rightarrow \mathbb{F}^k$ is the composition of surjective maps, so is surjective. The Dimension Theorem tells you that the the kernel of $\pi \circ f$ has dimension $n-k$.

Comment: $f$ is from $E$ to $ \mathbb F^n$ so $f\circ \pi$ isn't from $E$ to $\mathbb F^j$. No?

Comment: @user66407: sorry, I wrote my function composition the wrong way.

Comment: Ok it's beautifull. thanks.

Comment: I think that isn't usefull in my essay to complete the basis and I should consider directly the map $f:E\rightarrow \mathbb F^k$ and then I use the dimension theorem.

Comment: @user66407: your argument together with mine shows that $f$ is surjective.  There are other ways to argue for that, but one must give some argument for it, so I wouldn't necessarily revise your approach.

Answer (score 1):

You're pretty close.  Just let $f=(\ell _1,\cdots,\ell _k)$ map $E$ to $\mathbb{F}^k$.  The fact that $f=(\ell _1,\cdots,\ell _k)$ are linearly independent says precisely that the image is all of $\mathbb{F}^k$ (why?).  So by rank-nullity, the kernel of the map has dimension $\dim E - k$

Comment: For the sake of completeness do you explain why the image is all $\mathbb F^k$?

Comment: The assertion in the second sentence is equivalent to the fact that a $k \times n$ matrix with rank $k$ gives rise to a surjective linear map.  For this you can use rank-nullity and the dimension theorem.

Comment: The point is, if the image is not surjective, we can find a vector that is orthogonal to the image, and that gives you a linear dependence.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark I agree with you: since the rank  is the dimension of the image so if a $k\times n$ matrix has the rank $k$ then it's surjective but the question here why the image is all $\mathbb F^k$ i.e. why the rank is $k$?

Comment: @user66407: Because the rows are linearly independent.